Migration path to security-SE
There have been quite a few discussions about migration paths, but no one has asked for a specific one so far. And up until now, we don't have any migration path (except meta). So this question is:
Can we get a migration path to security-SE?
Due to the lack of reputation, I can't check the 10K tools  myself. But I would guess, security-SE is most likely on 1st or 2nd for our recent migrations. Crypto and Security SE are closely tied, as it was posted on both meta sites quite often:

Stats on Security-Meta (Nov 2011)
Stats on Security-Meta (Aug 2012)
Stats on Security-Meta (Dec 2012)
Stats on Crypto-Meta (Nov 2013)
Stats on Crypto-Meta (Aug 2014)

The last link shows the all time stats for crypto-SE back then: Security-SE leading with almost 4 times as many as the 2nd most migration target.
The reverse path already exists, due to the graduation of crypto-SE: Feb 2016 - with the tag "status completed"

In contrast to what you wrote, multiple people already asked for specific migration paths - including Security.SE. (example) Skipping the dupes et all, I'll simply point to the most recent and relevant Q&A: Migration Paths for Crypto.SE
As that Q&A's accepted answer explains the procedure SE expects from us, I tend to suggest following that lead. Especially, since "close reasons" have been voted upon already around and about three months ago. It probably makes sense for you to check Let's actually vote on our site-specific close reasons! (2016 edition) as it also includes a small overview of Crypto.SE's 2016 stats. (I knew it would pay off to create and share that "Status Quo" of our backend data back in March. Things haven't changed much since).

The other threads read like "Can we have migration paths please, e.g. this and that", I was aware of those. But I also had the impression, that nothing happened due to the request being not specific enough. But I missed the question with the close reasons, where the off-topic reason about policies scored badly. However, migration to security-SE is more than just policies.

@tylo I guess the main point here is (while keeping the vote-on-close-reasons Q&A in mind) the following: "... the volume of posts being migrated, and when it starts to create a burden on mods - who have to handle the flags and migrate the posts manually - ..." Fact is that we mods can easily handle related flags at Crypto.SE up until now. The volume of such flags is rather low. This is somewhat the main reason for the close-vote '16 Q&A not having too many specific migration paths either. Simply flag for mod attention with "Migrate to Xyz.SE" and it'll get handled by a mod quick & easy. ;)
